# Find the mass of a rod with the given density function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Reviewing for my final. I found this question and decided to do it. Can anyone look over my work and tell me if it's correct?

Find the mass of a rod of length 3 with density function $$p(x)=\frac{x^3}{(x^2+1)^3}$$ where x is the distance from one of the rod's ends.

So here's my work:
$$M=\int_0^3\frac{x^3}{(x^2+1)^3}dx$$

I'm having trouble integrating this, but I have reason to believe it can be done with $$u=x^2+1$$

After you integrate it should be easy to just plug in 3 and 0 to p'(x). Is that the correct way to do it, and how do I integrate that equation?

Comment: You mean linear mass density?

Comment: The question I was given by my professor just states mass of a rod, however I'm guessing she probably meant linear mass density?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made the right substitution. $$u=x^2+1\implies du=2xdx$$

$$\int\frac{x^2xdx}{u^3}$$
$$=\frac 1 2\int\frac{u-1}{u^3}du=\frac 1 2\int\frac{1}{u^2}-\frac{1}{u^3}du$$

Can
 you do it now?

Comment: Oh wow, how did I not get that to start with? That definitely helps me integrate, is my method for solving the problem correct though?

Comment: @user133707 It's perfect!

Comment: Thanks, that's a huge help!

Comment: @user133707 Anytime.